# Raspberry Pi webserver slow to respond to iOS devices on the LAN

Tags: python, ios, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have a Raspberry Pi running latest Raspbian executing a simple Python web server. Here is the code for that part:

```
# This is the main class for the web server
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    # These are the headers that are sent as a response to every request
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    # This is the new POST method to get around background refresh problems
    def do_POST(self):
        # Get the content of the POST request
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        # Split the text on the = of the key value pair, and keep the text of the operation.
        operationRequested = post_data.split("=")[1];
        logging.info(self.client_address[0] + " has requested operation " + operationRequested)

        # Handle each type of request. It's limited by the HTML file.
        if operationRequested == "openLeftDoor":
            leftDoor.openDoor()
        if operationRequested == "closeLeftDoor":
            leftDoor.closeDoor()
        if operationRequested == "openRightDoor":
            rightDoor.openDoor()
        if operationRequested == "closeRightDoor":
            rightDoor.closeDoor()

        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(operationRequested + " completed.")

    # This is how we handle a GET request. We sense the URL within this method
    def do_GET(self):

        logging.info(self.client_address[0] + " has requested page " + self.path)

        # Handle the GET for the log file.
        if self.path == '/getlogs':
            try:
                htmlPage = open(logFilename)
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()

                # Change carriage returns to HTML line breaks
                logFile = htmlPage.read()
                logFile = logFile.replace('\n', '<br>')

                self.wfile.write(logFile)
                self.wfile.write(htmlPage.read())
                htmlPage.close()
                return
            except IOError:
                logging.info("An IO Error happened during get logs!")

        # Handle the root request for the welcome page. This can't be an else as that disallows favicon requests.
        if self.path == "/":
            try:
                htmlPage = open("WelcomePage.html")
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(htmlPage.read())
                htmlPage.close()
                return
            except IOError as e:
                logging.info("An IO Error happened during get welcome page!")
                logging.info(repr(e))

# This is the entry point to the webserver. The try catch looks after closing the socket with Ctrl C.
try:
    myServer = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 80), MyHandler)
    myServer.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info(' received, shutting down the web server')
finally:
    myServer.server_close()
    logging.info("Server has been closed")
logging.info("Bye!")
```

This is only ever visited from my LAN, from both wired and wifi clients. I have never had an issue using Windows 10 based laptops, but perhaps 50% of the time on iOS the initial page is very slow to load, taking perhaps 30 seconds. The code isn't throwing any exceptions that I've been able to find.

This seems more prevalent when the page is added to the home screen on iOS versus when bookmarked in Safari. It's all using only IP addresses, no DNS resolution at all.

Once the iOS device has loaded the page the first time, any subsequent browsing to the same server is instantaneous.

I have verified that the Pi's wifi is not set to sleep, and it is an area of excellent RSSI / SNR. I have reproduced it across two different iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because I didn't have a favicon.ico and derivatives of it set up in the webserver.

When opening the page on an iPhone, particularly from the home screen, in the background the device would request these icons. The web server is not set up to handle simultaneous requests, so it is in a state waiting for each request to timeout before it handles the user's request and renders the page.

I resolved this by adding an else case to the do_GET method to handle a wildcard URL, returning a default icon.